# mongodb Field Level Updates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
label : {
   field1 : { .....},
   field2 : {.....}
}
db.collection.update({_id:"objectId"},{$set : label})
```

I have a single collection with multiple fileds and I want to update `field1` without removeing `field2`,  is this possible?

For example

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fa03....."), 
    "categories" : { 
        "category_name" : { 
            "en" : "Category Name", 
            "dk" : "Category Name DK" 
        }, 
        "color" : { "en" : "Color", "dk" : "Color DK" } 
    } 
}
```

Here I want to update `category_name` without removeing color. How do I update a single field1 in a record?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? What exactly do you mean by "I want to update field1 without reading field2"?

Comment: `{
 "_id" : ObjectId("56fa03....."),
 "categories" : {
  "category_name" : {
   "en" : "Category Name",
   "dk" : "Category Name DK"
  },
  "color" : {
   "en" : "Color",
   "dk" : "Color DK"
  }
 }
 }`
Here i want to update `category_name` without reading `color` ..

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName')
    .update("_id" : "objectId", 
        {$set : {"label.field1" : "value of field 1"}})
```

*based on documentation(v 3.2) :*

> The update() method either modifies specific fields in existing
> documents or replaces an existing document entirely.
>
> To update an embedded document or an array as a whole, specify the
> replacement value for the field. To update particular fields in an
> embedded document or in an array, use dot notation to specify the
> field

.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: done. @TobySpeight